# Replace Left Outer Join Null values with a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, isnull

I want to show the null values returned from the left outer join with a string " UnRegistered".

When the value is an integer or a bool, I just write:

```
 ISNULL(ReturnedValue, 0) AS ReturnedValue
```

but how can I make it:

```
 ISNULL(ReturnedValue, 'UnRegistered') AS ReturnedValue
```

I use MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, MeNoMore : Ms Sql Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you need a `varchar` value in the same field together with int/bool, you need to make sure every row of that field has the same data type.

```
Isnull(Convert(varchar(50), ReturnedValue), 'UnRegistered') AS ReturnedValue
```

***Or*** you can use a `CASE` as

```
Case when ReturnedValue is null then 'UnRegistered'
     else convert(varchar(50), ReturnedValue) end as ReturnedValue
```

Comment: Sorry, mistake with `"`, fixed now

Comment: The conversion outside the `ISNULL` is redundant, the `ISNULL` function has the same return type as the check expression, since you have already converted this to varchar, your second is converting varchar to varchar.